# What are app.iml and proguard-rules.pro doing in my Android app directory?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am studying the file/directory structure of an Android Studio project.

I don't understand the purpose of two files in /app directory:

1. app.iml
2. proguard-rules.pro

May I have some explanation on these files? If I want to share my project with other programmers, then do I have to include these files or just whatever that goes under /src plus build.gradle is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> May I have some explanation on these files?

`app.iml` is an Android Studio-generated file, based on the contents of your `build.gradle` files, that is used internally by the IDE. Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA; `.iml` files are IDEA's project metadata files. Android Studio does not consider them to be the system of record — the `build.gradle` files are — but presumably it was simpler to generate `.iml` files rather than rework IDEA to not need them.

`proguard-rules.pro` contains module-specific rules for configuring code obfuscation and shrinking. Presently, that is handled through a tool named ProGuard, which is why the file is named as it is.

> If I want to share my project with other programmers, then do I have to include these files or just whatever that goes under /src plus build.gradle is enough?

`app.iml` is output; it isn't in `build/` for technical reasons, I presume. You should not distribute this.

`proguard-rules.pro` is input. You should distribute this, even if it is largely empty at the moment.

Comment: I am programming for Android for 1 complete year and this is the first time I hear about ProGuard! Good explanation, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

app.iml is a file generated by Android Studio holding information about your project
It is the usual file format for IntelliJ.

proguard-rules.pro is used, if you enable proguard (minifyEnabled true) in your build.gradle file. It helps improving performance and keeping your app small.

To read more about proguard, read here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

From intelliJ documentation what I understand is you SHOULD share the iml files to for smooth collaboration with other developers who use android studio, I'm pasting the following text from their documentation, link here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827587-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

If you decide to share IDE project files with other developers, follow these guidelines:

Directory based project format (.idea directory)

This format is used by all the recent IDE versions by default. Here is what you need to share:

All the files under .idea directory in the project root except the workspace.xml and tasks.xml files which store user specific settings.

All the .iml module files that can be located in different module directories (applies to IntelliJ IDEA)

Be careful about sharing the following:

Android artifacts that produce a signed build (will contain keystore passwords)

In IDEA 13 and earlier dataSources.ids, datasources.xml can contain database passwords. IDEA 14 solves this problem.

You may consider not to share the following:

gradle.xml file

user dictionaries folder (to avoid conflicts if other developer has the same name)

XML files under .idea/libraries in case they are generated from Gradle project
Legacy project format (.ipr/.iml/.iws files)

Share the project .ipr file and all the .iml module files, don't share the .iws file as it stores user specific settings

Android studio will generate a .gitignore with the following values if you integrate git version control integration with the IDE

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
```

Comment: Mine is not IntelliJ IDEA, it is Android Studio. I think they are not the same.

Comment: Android studio uses IntelliJ IDEA, android studio is built on top of IDEA. An excerpt from this IntelliJ FAQ 

Is Android Studio a fork of IntelliJ IDEA?

No. Android Studio and the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA are built from the same code, and all of the changes in Android Studio are, and will continue to be, available in IntelliJ IDEA releases.

- See more at: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/#sthash.ZYVfSSrL.dpuf

Comment: @Ehsan for some reason im not able to edit the previous comment (could be character limit so I'm tagging you here now to notify you)